# Django Select2Widget has no attribute "attrs"

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates

I am trying to implement django_select2 in an form, but when I try to render the page I get the following error:

```
type object 'Select2Widget' has no attribute 'attrs'
```

The widget is declared like this(it's a modelform):

```
self.fields["prodotti_var"].widget = Select2Widget
```

Here is the complete traceback:

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/magazzino/bolle_in/5/

Django Version: 2.0.6
Python Version: 3.6.5
Installed Applications:
['django_select2',
 'actstream',
 'amministrazione',
 'clienti',
 'fornitori',
 'prodotti',
 'documenti',
 'fatture',
 'admin_interface',
 'colorfield',
 'magazzino',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'django.contrib.sites',
 'django.contrib.humanize',
 'widget_tweaks']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']


Template error:
In template /home/matteo/Naturelab/amministrazione/templates/base_site.html, error at line 0
   type object 'Select2Widget' has no attribute 'attrs'
   1 : {% load static %}
   2 : {% load widget_tweaks %}
   3 : <!DOCTYPE html>
   4 : <!--
   5 : Template Name: LuMa CMS
   6 : Version: 1.0
   7 : Author: LucyT & MatFire1999
   8 : Contact: hello@lumacms.com
   9 : -->
   10 : <html lang="it">


Traceback:

File "/home/matteo/virtualenvs/Naturelab/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in inner
  35.             response = get_response(request)

File "/home/matteo/virtualenvs/Naturelab/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  128.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "/home/matteo/virtualenvs/Naturelab/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  126.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "/home/matteo/Naturelab/magazzino/views.py" in ddt_in_detail
  76.     return render(request, "ddt_in_mod.html", context)

File "/home/matteo/virtualenvs/Naturelab/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/shortcuts.py" in render
  36.     content = loader.render_to_string(template_name, context, request, using=using)

File "/home/matteo/virtualenvs/Naturelab/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/loader.py" in render_to_string
  62.     return template.render(context, request)

File "/home/matteo/virtualenvs/Naturelab/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py" in render
  61.             return self.template.render(context)

File "/home/matteo/virtualenvs/Naturelab/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  175.                     return self._render(context)

File "/home/matteo/virtualenvs/Naturelab/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in _render
  167.         return self.nodelist.render(context)

File "/home/matteo/virtualenvs/Naturelab/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  943.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "/home/matteo/virtualenvs/Naturelab/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render_annotated
  910.             return self.render(context)

File "/home/matteo/virtualenvs/Naturelab/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py" in render
  155.             return compiled_parent._render(context)

File "/home/matteo/virtualenvs/Naturelab/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in _render
  167.         return self.nodelist.render(context)

File "/home/matteo/virtualenvs/Naturelab/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  943.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "/home/matteo/virtualenvs/Naturelab/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render_annotated
  910.             return self.render(context)

File "/home/matteo/virtualenvs/Naturelab/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py" in render
  67.                 result = block.nodelist.render(context)

File "/home/matteo/virtualenvs/Naturelab/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  943.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "/home/matteo/virtualenvs/Naturelab/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render_annotated
  910.             return self.render(context)

File "/home/matteo/virtualenvs/Naturelab/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py" in render
  211.                     nodelist.append(node.render_annotated(context))

File "/home/matteo/virtualenvs/Naturelab/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render_annotated
  910.             return self.render(context)

File "/home/matteo/virtualenvs/Naturelab/lib/python3.6/site-packages/widget_tweaks/templatetags/widget_tweaks.py" in render
  197.         return str(bounded_field)

File "/home/matteo/virtualenvs/Naturelab/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/html.py" in <lambda>
  380.     klass.__str__ = lambda self: mark_safe(klass_str(self))

File "/home/matteo/virtualenvs/Naturelab/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/forms/boundfield.py" in __str__
  36.         return self.as_widget()

File "/home/matteo/virtualenvs/Naturelab/lib/python3.6/site-packages/widget_tweaks/templatetags/widget_tweaks.py" in as_widget
  30.         process(widget or self.field.widget, attrs, attribute, value)

File "/home/matteo/virtualenvs/Naturelab/lib/python3.6/site-packages/widget_tweaks/templatetags/widget_tweaks.py" in process
  63.         elif widget.attrs.get(attribute):

Exception Type: AttributeError at /magazzino/bolle_in/5/
Exception Value: type object 'Select2Widget' has no attribute 'attrs'
```

Can you guys help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By writing:

```
self.fields["prodotti_var"].widget = Select2Widget
```

you did *not* construct a widget, but passed a reference to the `Select2Widget` class into the `self.fields`.

You need to *call* the constructor, so:

```
self.fields["prodotti_var"].widget = Select2Widget()
```